# one sub procedure / change text color in rich text box / without button handler

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

everyone! I've been at this for a while, and I'm not sure how this issue can be resolved:

I'm working on a project in VB.Net, and I have a form with a rich text box. I have a groupbox with 4 radio buttons inside that are intended to change the font color of the text. Coincidentally, I have to repeat this same functionality for a 2nd set of radio buttons that would change the text font family.

At any rate what I've only been able to do is the following to successfully change the font color of whatever text I highlight in the rich text box:

```
Private Sub rbtnBlack_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnBlack.CheckedChanged
    rtbxTextEditor.SelectionColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub rbtnRed_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnRed.CheckedChanged
    rtbxTextEditor.SelectionColor = Color.Crimson
End Sub

Private Sub rbtnGreen_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnGreen.CheckedChanged
    rtbxTextEditor.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGreen
End Sub

Private Sub rbtnBlue_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtnBlue.CheckedChanged
    rtbxTextEditor.SelectionColor = Color.RoyalBlue
End Sub
```

Is there a way that I could write a sub (I'm assuming I would use a sub, since I don't think I need to return anything, thus eliminating the use of a function) that would handle the action of changing the selected text color in the rich text box without having to use a separate sub for each radio button? Mind you, per my teacher's specs, she doesn't use a button handler for any of this.

Thanks, and please let me know if I've supplied enough information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
Private Sub somethingChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles rbtnBlack.CheckedChanged,rbtnRed.CheckedChanged,rbtnGreen.CheckedChanged ' etc ...
  IF sender = rbtnBlack THEN
    rtbxTextEditor.SelectionColor = Color.Black
  END IF

  IF sender = rbtnRed THEN
    rtbxTextEditor.SelectionColor = Color.Crimson
  END IF

  ' etc

End Sub
```

Comment: Hogan: Thanks for the response. I ended up figuring it out and it was basically the same as your solution.